# Reading data from res.end()

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm sending a simple data back from the server to the client.

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res) { 
    var userName = "John";
    res.end(JSON.stringify({"error":"", "user": userName}));
});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ...
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType: "json"
})
    .done(function(data) {
        // send join message
        var resData = JSON.parse(data);
        alert("hello"); // this doesn't show up
        });
    });
});
```

But in the browser console, I get this error - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o".

If I do `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` on the content, it works fine.

```
alert(JSON.parse (JSON.stringify({"error":"", "user": userName})).user);
```

And also, `.done` works fine without a data payload from the server i.e. the `alert("hello")` works.

So, I'm guessing something fishy is happening while sending data within `res.end()`. Please help.

While at it, it would be nice if you can also tell me how to do the same using res.json() and which one is preferable.

Comment: Why dont you simply use `res.json({"error":"", "user": userName})`?
Thats the better way to send JSON responses.

Comment: What does `data` look like in your `done` function? What does `typeof data` return?

Comment: @tkone - `typeof (data)` is an `object` ... surprising, as I thought after `stringify`, it should have been a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you set `dataType: 'json'` in your jQuery request. This causes the response from the server to be automatically parsed as JSON, so it will return the object rather than the raw server response.